# Stata: Keep the first observation by group

Tags: stata

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
id  firm  earnings    A
1   A      100        0
1   A      200        0
2   B      50         1
2   B      70         1  
3   C      900        0
```

bys id firm, I want to keep only the first observation if A==0 and want to keep all the observations if A==1.

I've tried the following code:

```
if A==0{
bys id firm: keep if _n==1
 }
```

However, this code drops all the _n>1 observations no matter what the A value is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if (conditional) {do something}` syntax is used in control flow rather than in defining variables. As you have it now Stata is only testing if `A==1` in the first row. Try adding additional conditions using **and** (`&`) or **or** (`|`) statements. Try this:

`bys id firm: keep if (_n==1 & A==0) | A==1`

Comment: @adamsalenushka I'll add that if `earnings` plays into your keep decision, you should explicitly add it to the by sort: `bysort id firm (earnings)`. If you want earnings sorted in descending order generate the negative of earnings and place that in the parentheses.